# Crash when releasing UIImage after memory-warning

Tags: iphone, uiimage, warnings, release, dealloc

I am quite new to the iphone development and I'm encountering a weird crash in my application. Indeed, my application always crashes after I've simulated a memory warning. I can reproduce this behavior every time and have managed to isolate the faulty line :).

I'm working in a custom UITableViewController, delivering custom UITableViewCells.

```
@implementation CustomTableViewController
// [...]
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyTableViewCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

if ([indexPath row] < [dataList childCount])
{
    cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (nil == cell) 
    {
        cell = [[[KpowUITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        KUICustomView* customView = [[KUICustomView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [(KpowUITableViewCell*)cell setFrontView:customView];
        [customView release];
    }

    KUICustomView* cView = [(KpowUITableViewCell*)cell frontView];
    [cView setDataObject:[dataList getChildAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]; // The crash happens in this function
}
// [...]
```

Here's the function where I set the custom data object for my cell view :

```
-(void)setDataObject:(DataObject *)do
{
    [do retain];
    [dataObject release];
    dataObject = do;

    NSString* defaultPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/default_image.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    UIImage* defaultImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:defaultPath];
    [self setImage: defaultImage];//[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_image"]]; // The crash happens in this function
    [defaultImage release];
    // [...]
```

And finally, here's where the magic happens :

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    [img retain];
    NSLog(@"setImage : old image > %@/%@/%i", [image description],         [[image class]description], [image retainCount]);
    [image release]; // CRASH EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    image = img;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

So, everything works just fine in a normal scenario. But if I simulate a memory warning, scroll my UITableView and all these functions get called, the application crashes. If I remove the [image release], no crash (but 'Hai there memory leaks'). 
The output of the NSLog is always something like :

> `setImage : old image > <UIImage: 0x4b54910>/UIImage/1`

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong, or what I could do to work around this issue. 
Here's a screenshot of Xcode debugger...

http://img30.imageshack.us/i/debuggerscreen.png/

Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance

**Edit 1:**
@bbum
Build and Analyze showed me some unrelated warnings, but still useful. Didn't even see it was there

There is one other place where I set the image. In the `setDataObject`, the image is just a placeholder. I launch the download of the real image asynchronously, and get it back in `requestDidFinishLoad`. The method goes like this :

```
- (void)requestDidFinishLoad:(KURLRequest*)request
{
    if (request == currentRequest) 
    {
        UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[request data]];

        if (nil != img)
            [self setImage:img];

        [img release];
    }

    if (currentRequest == request)
        currentRequest = nil;
    [request release];
}
```

I runned instruments with NSZombie Detection, and the result seems to point in another direction. Here's a screenshot :

http://img13.imageshack.us/i/zombieinstrument.jpg/

I'm not quite sure what to do with that yet, but the investigation progresses :)

Comment: A retain count can never be zero.  retainCount is useless.

Comment: @bbum I know I can't trust retainCount, but at some point I'm willing to try anything...ANYTHING :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka!
I finally found what I did wrong. 
When the image is asynchronously loaded, it uses data coming from a custom object used for caching, stored in a cache manager. When a memory warning is issued, the cache manager releases everything, destroying the cache object from memory. Here's what my dealloc looked like in my "cachable object" :

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    // [...]
    [data dealloc];
    // [...]
}
```

Yeah, I was explicitly calling dealloc... So of course when UIImage wanted to release its own pointer on the data, it failed...

I feel so stupid ^^.
(I'm always having a hard time debugging my own programs, since I sometimes assume parts of code as "OK", and I don't even think to look there...)

Bottom line : **NSZombie was really useful** (thanks @bbum) to find out the real culprit. And **never (?) call dealloc explicitly**.

(is there anyway to "close" this question?

Comment: Generally, you should accept the answer that helped the most and then add your solution to your question (which, thank you for adding the eventual solution -- always helpful to anyone else who happens to stumble upon your question!)

Answer (score 4):

```
[image release]; // CRASH EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Your backtrace shows that you are crashing in the `dealloc` method of `UIImage`.  You have over-released `image` somewhere.

First, try "Build and Analyze" and see if it barfs up any useful warnings.  Fix them.

Next, turn on Zombie Detection try to reproduce the problem.  It may provide clues.

Note that `@property` is "merely" convenience for declaring a setter/getter method pair (or one of 'em).   `[foo setImage:bar]` is exactly equivalent regardless of whether you use `@property` or declare the method directly.  Similarly `foo.image = bar;` is exactly the same as `[foo setImage:bar];`.

Finally, is that *all* the code that handles your `image`?   How do you handle the low memory warning?

Also, you'd be better off if your setter did *not* call `setNeedsDisplay:`.   Use a simple `@property` and `@synthesize` the setter/getter.   Then, when you call the setter, call `setNeedsDisplay:` on the line after.  This keeps the business of setting up the UI isolated from determining when the display needs to happen.

---

Aha!  Your zombie stuff was very useful.  In particular, it looks like you are prematurely releasing an URLConnection, which then causes an NSData to be released too soon.  This could easily be the source of your problem or, at the least, should be fixed before trying to fix *this* issue.

Comment: I don't know if you're notified when I modify my post (see edit 1).

Also I'm not doing anything in my controllers regarding memory warnings, just the default implementation. I do empty some caches (one stores data used for images, so it could be related).

I don't like the "dot" notation for properties ^^. It looks like you're just assigning something, when really there could be much more going on (since it's a method).

Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yup -- I see your notifs.   The dot notation is a take-it-or-leave-it kinda thing.  You can leave it if you want. :)  The code you added calls `setMoviePosterImage:`, not `setImage:`.  Does the former call the latter?

Comment: `setMoviePosterImage:` IS `setImage`. I just renamed it when first publishing it to make it more clear and relevant to my problem. Looks like I achieved exactly the opposite.

Comment: oups, I didn't see you had edited your answer. It would have save me a few more hours >_<

Answer (score 0):

You are probably releasing the image in response to the memory warning without setting it to nil as well. So when you are calling `setImage:` you are releasing an already released object, hence the crash. Try something like:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [image release]; image = nil;
}
```

or if `image` is declared as a property

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.image = nil;
}
```

Comment: `UITableViewCell` is not a `UIViewController`, so there's no `viewDidUnload` method :/. And I'm not implementing it in my `CustomTableViewController`.  
Also image is not a property, there's just the setter. So it can't be modified from outside any other way (at least that's my understanding).

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to address @sabby's misconception:

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    [img retain]; // img rc +1
    image = img; 
    if(image)
    {
        [image release]; // img rc -1
    }
    // image set, but not retained by `self`
}
```

End result?  A setter method that does not retain the item set. Combine that with:

```
- initWithImage:anImage
{
     if (self=[super init]) {
           image = [anImage retain];
     }
     return self;
}
```

The above setter will *leak* the original image passed to `init`, over-release any image passed to `setImage:` and, if the app survives long enough, quite likely crash in:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [image release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do in this way, Might it help you

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    [img retain];
    NSLog(@"setImage : old image > %@/%@/%i", [image description],         [[image class]description], [image retainCount]);
     // CRASH EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    image = img;
if(image)
{
[image release];
}

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I haven't checked it my self but the reason for your crashing is the release of image.

Comment: Yeah but If I do that, the old image is never released, and the new one not retained (successively calling retain and release on it).

Comment: This recommendation guarantees that `image` will be a dangling pointer after calling `setImage:`.... bad idea.

Comment: @Kombucha, thats checking that if the image object is present then release it else not.So the image will only be released if the object would be pointing, and moreover if your image object is globally this is the right way and you can also release it in dealloc method.Try to do some memory management.....

Comment: @bbum ,this is the right way..........the app is crashing due to early release of image object,and the condition works for good

Comment: No, no it isn't.  `if (image) [image release];` is *never* the right thing to do (not even when maintaining a weak reference).  At the end of it, the retain count for `img` is unchanged meaning that the `image` will quite likely be deallocated out from under the object.

Comment: @bbum.You mean conditions are not the right way .......Hummmm...Good going dear.......Whether there is a reference or weak reference to memory.......if you are going to realse non referenced memory there would be crash bbbbbbbuuummmmmmmm.Now you can try.......helping him.....

Comment: Sigh -- see my additional answer.  Comments don't allow for enough code formatting to make it clear.